# Visual Studio 2010 Rename Project and cause Namespacing to correspond

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, namespaces

In Visual Studio 2010 I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 project called blahblah.  As such, all the code within this project is namespaced as blahblah.Controllers, blahblah.Configuration etc.

I want to be able to rename the project to blahblah.Web.  Now I know I can just right click on the project and go to rename, but if I do this, none of the namespacing matches anymore.

I would like some way to convert all namespacing so that it is relative to the new project name.  blahblah.Web.Controllers, blahblah.Web.Configuration, etc.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use ReSharper's 'Refactor' menu and select 'Adjust Namespaces'. http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Adjust_Namespaces.html

Comment: I do have ReSharper. So after I did a rename of my project from blahblah to blahblah.Web, I did as you directed and Selected from the Menu: Resharper > Refactor > Adjust Namespaces...  But when the dialog pops up it tells me that there are no files found with inconsistent namespaces.

Comment: Much preferable to the Replace in Files nightmare.

Comment: Also, do not forget to go to the project properties window and change 'Default namespace:' setting to match the new name of the project.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use a **Replace in Files** or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

Search for the full previous namespace e.g. `namespace blahblah.Web.Controllers` and replace with the new namespace e.g. `namespace blahblah.Web.Configuration`.

Also, remember the change the **default namespace** in the **project properties** so that any new files get created in the correct namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Without third party add-ons: Edit > Find and Replace > Replace in Files

Find what: namespace blahblah
Replace with: namespace blahblah.Web

Click on Replace All.

Answer (score 0):

Using Find and Replace

Do a search for "using blahblah." and replace it with "using blahblah.Web."

Ignore the quotation marks there just to show the string to use. 
That should do it easily enough.